# decode_pad not exist while trying to build streaming with GStreamer 1.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, streaming, gstreamer

I'm trying to implement the code from this [link](https://samirghimire.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/streaming-with-python-and-gstreamer/) in python 2.7 with Gstreamer 1.45. This code is written in GStreamer 0.1. Alas I can't find any parallel commands for connect, e.g. when I get to the line

`decode.connect(“new-decoded-pad”, new_decode_pad)`

I get the error `NameError:name new_decode_pad is not defined`

I tried using the doucmentation of [PyGI](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/) but it gives no results about this command. Which command is equivallent for this command? Can anybody supply me a link for a code snippet of functioning code that streams audio in Gstreamer 1.0 (or a comprehensive guide for transforming codes in GStreamer 0.1 to Gstreamer 1.0).

Answer (score 1):

Using the “pad-added” signal instead in 1.0.

http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gst-plugins-base-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-base-plugins-decodebin2.html#GstDecodeBin2-removed-decoded-pad

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstElement.html#GstElement-pad-added

Comment: Thanks, Still I can't understand how to use it . Is there any good tutorial for Gstreamer 1.0 for Python (or for 0.10) which gives several examples?

Comment: Thanks again. Are there any tutorials for version 1.0?